# make several operations in a dataframe at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do in a smart way several calculation by using `.groupby` with `pandas` `dataframe`, with the following data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                              'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                       'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                              'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                       'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                       'D' : np.random.randn(8)})
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one  0.469112 -0.861849
1  bar    one -0.282863 -2.104569
2  foo    two -1.509059 -0.494929
3  bar  three -1.135632  1.071804
4  foo    two  1.212112  0.721555
5  bar    two -0.173215 -0.706771
6  foo    one  0.119209 -1.039575
7  foo  three -1.044236  0.271860
```

I would like to compute in the shorter and faster way the following **Output**:

```
 A    B          var1     var2      var3
bar  one      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
     three    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
     two      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
foo  one      0.822999  19.705290 0.731207
     three    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
     two      0.229541  5.509553  0.697971
```

For the moment I know how to do it in a separate way:

```
# lambda functions to apply
diff = lambda x: max(x)-min(x)
per = lambda x: (max(x)-min(x))/max(x)
ratio1 = lambda x: (max(x)-min(x))/ len(x)

# grouping using col C
df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].apply(diff)   # var1

#Grouping using col D
df.groupby(['A','B'])['D'].apply(per)    # var2
df.groupby(['A','B'])['D'].apply(ratio1) #var3
```

Edit:
I know how to join all results in a dataframe but I am wondering how to do these 3 operations in one. Any advice is accepted even to not to do all in one because of low performance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `agg()`:

```
df.groupby(['A','B']).agg({'C': diff, 'D': [per, ratio1]})
```

To skip the renaming part you can call your functions `var1`, `var2` and `var3` and use it in `groupby`.

```
var1 = lambda x: max(x)-min(x)
var2 = lambda x: (max(x)-min(x))/max(x)
var3 = lambda x: (max(x)-min(x))/ len(x)
df.groupby(['A','B']).agg({'C': var1, 'D': [var2, var3]})
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
```

**EDIT**

Try with:

```
def var1(x): return max(x)-min(x)
def var2(x): return (max(x)-min(x))/max(x)
def var3(x): return (max(x)-min(x))/ len(x)
```

**EDIT of EDIT**

This works for me on `pandas` version `0.19.2`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                              'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                       'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                              'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                       'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                       'D' : np.random.randn(8)})

def var1(x): return max(x)-min(x)
def var2(x): return (max(x)-min(x))/max(x)
def var3(x): return (max(x)-min(x))/ len(x)

df = df.groupby(['A','B']).agg({'C': var1, 'D': [var2, var3]})

df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
```

Comment: @zipa .Is not working. Error: Function names must be unique, found multiple named <lambda>

Comment: Okay, change `lambda`s to classic functions :)

Comment: FYI it is a [known issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7186)

Comment: OK I will fin it out, it is still not working. 'Index' object has no attribute 'droplevel'

Comment: You din't assign groupby to variable `df`. See the edit.