# Pandas Groupby: How to use two lambda functions?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I can currently do the following in Pandas, but I get a stern finger wagging from FutureWarning:

```
grpd = df.groupby("rank").agg({
    "mean": np.mean, "meian": np.median, "min": np.min, "max": np.max, 
    "25th percentile": lambda x: np.percentile(x, 25),
    "75th percentile": lambda x: np.percentile(x, 75)
})
```

The following throws an error because I have two lambda functions:

```
percentile_25 = lambda x: np.percentile(x, 25)
percentile_75 = lambda x: np.percentile(x, 75)

df = diffs[["User Installs", "rank"]].dropna()
grpd = df.groupby("shopping_rank").agg([
    np.mean, np.median, np.min, np.max, 
    percentile_25, percentile_75
])
```

This throws:

```
SpecificationError: Function names must be unique, found multiple named <lambda>
```

The only way I can seem to make this work (without ignoring the warning, which I should probably just do) is with an elaborate process like the following

1. Define my DF with one lambda function (25th percentile), and everything else I need (min, max, etc.)
2. rename the cols to get rid of the MultiIndex
3. Create ANOTHER DF, do ANOTHER grouping, this time with the other column I want (75th percentile)
4. Rename cols again (thanks MultiIndex!)
5. Join back to the original DF on the index

Is there something I'm missing here? Surely there's a better way to do what I imagine is a pretty common thing (using two aggregations that aren't directly importable from numpy).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make several operations in a dataframe at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46812223/make-several-operations-in-a-dataframe-at-once)

Comment: A function is a function. A `lambda` expression is simply one way to create a value of type `function`.

Comment: @chepner Sorry if I was unclear. I don't care about how the function is defined, lambda expressions seem to exist for this exact use case, so I was a bit confused as to why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Lambda expressions are used to pass an anonymous function as an argument to a function, or possibly as the value for a key in a mapping. If you are just going to assign it to a name, you may as well just use a `def` statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7186), use:

```
def percentile_25(x): return np.percentile(x, 25)
def percentile_75(x): return np.percentile(x, 75)
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I would also recommend defining them as partials with `functools.partial`

Comment: I prefer named functions over lambda, since suitable function names *can* avoid calling `.rename()` on the data frame afterwards (when passing multiple functions).

Answer (score 4):

Try the following little hack:

```
percentile_25 = lambda x: np.percentile(x, 25)
percentile_25.__name__ = 'percentile_25'
percentile_75 = lambda x: np.percentile(x, 75)
percentile_75.__name__ = 'percentile_75'
```

Comment: Just use `def percentile_25(x): return np.percentile(x, 25)`. There's no reason to use a `lambda` expression here.

Comment: @chepner, i used it, because OP asked: `"How to use two lambda functions?"`

Comment: I was thinking about something like this, I'm agnostic about how to build the function -- I've always used lambda functions for this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a result column name.

An alternative:

```
percentile_25 = lambda x: np.percentile(x, 25)
percentile_75 = lambda x: np.percentile(x, 75)

grouped = df.groupby("field1")
grouped.agg({
    'field2': {'percentile_25': percentile_25, 'percentile_75': percentile_75}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another, similar way to [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46814192/4049396), however, it allows you to create an arbitrary number of lambda functions. So, if we want each 10th percentile can do as follows,

```
n_percentile_groups = 10
lambda_list = []

for pcntl in np.linspace(10, 100, n_percentile_groups):
    lmbd = lambda x, pcntl=pcntl: np.percentile(x, int(pcntl))
    lmbd.__name__ = 'percentile_%d' % pcntl
    lambda_list.append(lmbd)
```

Now pass `lambda_list` to `groupby.agg()` or append with other functions lists, e.g, `lambda_list + [np.mean, np.min, ...]`.

If you instead wanted just 5 different percentiles then you could change `n_percentile_groups = 5`.

Ultimately, I am not sure if it is a robust or good way of doing this - with a variable number of lambdas - but since the [groupby deprecation - 0.21](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/whatsnew.html#deprecate-groupby-agg-with-a-dictionary-when-renaming) it seems to be the only way I know. Comments on this very welcome.