# apply two lambda functions on a pandas dataframe at column and row levels

Tags: pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

I would like to *groupby* a pandas dataframe based on *key_col* list and in each group perform two things:

1. First sort the values based on the *from_date_col*
2. perform a shift on the *to_date_col* column and make a comparison which returns a boolean and says if there is an overlap on the dates or no (see test example below)

My current code looks like this:

```
def get_overlapping_date_range(df, key_col, from_date_col, to_date_col):

df['is_overlap'] = (df
                    .groupby(key_col)
                    .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(from_date_col))
                    .apply(lambda x: (x[to_date_col].shift() - x[from_date_col]) > timedelta(0))
                    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))

return df
```

These lambdas work separately but not together. The error I get is: `KeyError: ('to', 'occurred at index id')`

To make it clear I want to give this input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','from','to'], index=range(7),
                  data=[[878, date(2006,1,1), date(2007,10,1)],
                        [878, date(2007,10,2), date(2008,12,1)],
                        [878, date(2008,12,2), date(2010,4,3)],
                        [879, date(2010,4,4), date(2199,5,10)],
                        [879, date(2016,5,12), date(2199,12,31)],
                        [880, date(2011,7,8), date(2013,3,3)],
                        [880, date(2010,2,12), date(2015,5,5)]])
```

and call `get_overlapping_date_range(df, 'id', 'from', 'to')` and get this output:

```
        id        from          to  is_overlap
0  878  2006-01-01  2007-10-01       False
1  878  2007-10-02  2008-12-01       False
2  878  2008-12-02  2010-04-03       False
3  879  2010-04-04  2199-05-10       False
4  879  2016-05-12  2199-12-31        True
5  880  2011-07-08  2013-03-03       False
6  880  2010-02-12  2015-05-05        True
```

The reason I want to do the sort in the groupby is that the dataframe is too big.
How can I apply two lambdas on a groupby when there is a mix of col and row manipulation? all the [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46813921/pandas-groupby-how-to-use-two-lambda-functions) I have found are on column based activities.

Comment: 3rd index - Year is correct ? mentioned as 2199 ?

Comment: Taking Year as 2019.

Comment: Below code ok ?

Comment: Is there any issue in replying ?

Comment: Kindly respond, so that I can close this issue

Comment: Hi Thanks but this is not working

Comment: Its Working correctly. Output compared with Expected Output. Any Way edited answer once again with full details. Pls check

Comment: Welcome, glad it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','from','to'], index=range(7),
              data=[[878, datetime(2006,1,1), datetime(2007,10,1)],
                    [878, datetime(2007,10,2), datetime(2008,12,1)],
                    [878, datetime(2008,12,2), datetime(2010,4,3)],
                    [879, datetime(2010,4,4), datetime(2199,5,10)],
                    [879, datetime(2016,5,12), datetime(2199,12,31)],
                    [880, datetime(2011,7,8), datetime(2013,3,3)],
                    [880, datetime(2010,2,12), datetime(2015,5,5)]])
print(df)

id       from         to
0  878 2006-01-01 2007-10-01
1  878 2007-10-02 2008-12-01
2  878 2008-12-02 2010-04-03
3  879 2010-04-04 2199-05-10
4  879 2016-05-12 2199-12-31
5  880 2011-07-08 2013-03-03
6  880 2010-02-12 2015-05-05

def check_date_by_id(df):

    df['prevFrom'] = df['from'].shift()
    df['prevTo'] = df['to'].shift()

    def check_date_by_row(x):

        if pd.isnull(x.prevFrom) or pd.isnull(x.prevTo):
             x['overlap'] = False
             return x

        latest_start = max(x['from'], x.prevFrom)
        earliest_end = min(x['to'], x.prevTo)
        x['overlap'] = int((earliest_end - latest_start).days) + 1 > 0
        return x

    return df.apply(check_date_by_row, axis=1).drop(['prevFrom','prevTo'], axis=1)

print(df.groupby('id').apply(check_date_by_id))

id       from         to  overlap
0  878 2006-01-01 2007-10-01    False
1  878 2007-10-02 2008-12-01    False
2  878 2008-12-02 2010-04-03    False
3  879 2010-04-04 2199-05-10    False
4  879 2016-05-12 2199-12-31     True
5  880 2011-07-08 2013-03-03    False
6  880 2010-02-12 2015-05-05     True
```